# Custom Wordpress Plugins, Are They All Just Petty?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying my hand at Wordpress plugin development. From all of the getting started examples and tutorials I have seen, it seems as though plugins can do little more than, say, add a "Bookmark This" at the end of a post, add an icon next to external links, or other relatively minor enhancements to existing features.

I would like to develop an extension (might that be the better word?) where a user can go to `my-wordpress-site.com/the-extension` and access the features of the web application. However, since all extensions must placed within `wp-includes/plugins/the-extension`, does that mean that is the only way the plugins can be accessed?

How could I design the extension and containing pages to be accessed with a URL like this: `my-wordpress-site.com/the-extension`?

Comment: WP has sort of a [rewrite "API"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) which you can use to map that URL to your plugin actions

Comment: @OneTrickPony Hmm... if I redirect user traffic to the `wp-includes/plugins/the-extension` directory, will Wordpress still treat the URLs as a plugin (i.e. add a header, footer, etc...) or will it just pass execute the PHP within the script, and that's it?

Comment: Plugins operate on WP pages, posts, whatever. You can create a WP page and your plugin can do whatever it wants to it. Plugins certainly aren't limited to simple things like adding a bookmark. Just look at the plugin repository to see the vast array of complex plugins available.

Comment: You can write a plugin to do almost anything in wp. The tutorials may seem limited, but typically tutorials are for just getting started. The API docs will be the real source for serious plugins. And as people have said, shortcodes for flexibility can help you place your plugin on any url on your site. On the other hand, you can hook your plugin to automatically process on all pages or whatever you specify.

Comment: Small salad of interesting stuff: [\[1\]](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/download-monitor/) - [\[2\]](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/editorial-calendar/) - [\[3\]](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) - [\[4\]](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) - [\[5\]](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/docs-to-wordpress/) - [\[6\]](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wedevs-project-manager/) - [\[7\]](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
// register your rewrite rule
add_action('init', function(){
  add_rewrite_rule('the-extension$', 'index.php?my_plugin_action=do_stuff', 'top');
});

// register your query variable
add_filter('query_vars', function($vars){
  $vars[] = 'my_plugin_action';
  return $vars;
});

// process request
add_action('parse_request', function($wp){

  // check if this is your request; do nothing if not
  if(!isset($wp->query_vars['my_plugin_action']))
    return;

  // otherwise do your stuff
  printf('Hello Pony. You requested "%s"', $wp->query_vars['my_plugin_action']);
  exit;
});
```

This will only work after you go to your dashboard > settings > permalinks and click the save button to flush rewrite rules, because WP apparently keeps some kind of cache of all rewrite rules.

Then accessing `yourwordpresssite.com/the-extension` should display the hello message

Comment: This is also kind of like what you had mentioned: http://tutorialzine.com/2012/10/todo-app-wordpress/

Comment: That code does a regex match against `$_REQUEST`, while this one let's WP handle that. WordPress fans would tell you to follow WP standards and use the provided API. I'm not going to do that because WP standards are pretty low anyway, so just choose the method you like more :)

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked on Wordpress plugins of this scale, but here is the general idea.

Your plugin needs to do the following:

1. [Generate a shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).
2. [Generate a page](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-create-a-new-page-with-the-plugin-im-building) with the shortcode.

Using a shortcode allows users to move the plugin's page anywhere.

Also, you could look into [setting up administration pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus) for the plugin as an option..

Comment: Hmm... shortcodes seem promising! The idea of using Wordpress as the basis for plugin was development was in the hopes it would be quick. In your experience, is this true?

Comment: I think it really depends on what you're trying to do. If it fits within the capabilities and goals of Wordpress, then sure. If not, you might as well write it custom.

Comment: Lastly, since this plugin will have dynamically generated pages (and by that I mean something like, say product.php?id=2379) and form processors, would shortcodes and plugins still fit nicely into these requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples of plugins that float outside of the wp-content directory (see installation instructions):

- [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/)
- [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/)